# How do i create a list of Objects in Java

Tags: java, android

I have a class file called MarkerCustom.  MarkerCustom has a constructor that takes three variables of different types.

```
public MarkerCustom(int myInt, String, myString, BitmapData myBitmap) {
```

From my main Main activity i want to load a GLSurface view that will take an ArrayList of every instance of MarkerCustom that i will want to load into the GLSurface along with the data that will be passed into each instance of MarkerCustom's constructor.

Lets call the Array List `myMarkers`;

i need `myMarkers` to look like this:

```
myMarkers[0] = [1, "hello", bitMapData1]
myMarkers[1] = [66, "johnHandy", bitmapData2]
```

i am fairly new to java and its casting ect confuses me a bit having come from AS3

**EDIT**

So following AKhill's answer below i have edited my `GLSurfaceView` to accept an ArrayList as shown below.  But the `MarkerCustom` Class needs to be created from each listed in that ArrayList in the constructor in a manner that its is accessible in the `onSurfaceCreate` and the `onDrawFrame` method of the `GLSurfaceView`

Please see those methods and the for loops/comments in this class below:

```
public class GLLayer extends GLSurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback, Renderer {

    private Context context;

    ArrayList <MarkerCustom> locationTags;

    private PhoneOrientation phoneOri;


    public GLLayer(Context context, int orientation, ArrayList<MarkerCustom> custMarkers) {
        super(context);
        locationTags = custMarkers;

        this.context = context;

        phoneOri=new PhoneOrientation(context); // sensor manager and interpreter

         for(int i =0; i<locationTags.size(); i++){

            //Need to create a an instance of each MarkerCustom
            // something like MarkerCustom locationTags[i]; = new MarkerCustom (its params);
        }
        this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        this.setRenderer(this);
        phoneOri.start(context, orientation);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        float floatMat[]=phoneOri.getMatrix();

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);


        gl.glLoadMatrixf(floatMat, 0);


        for(int i=0;i<loacationTags.size();i++){
            gl.glPushMatrix();

            //locationTags[i].draw(gl);
            gl.glLoadMatrixf(floatMat,0);
        }


         gl.glPushMatrix();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
      if(height == 0) {                    
        height = 1;                         
        }
        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    

        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 35.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 5.0f, 200.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 1.0f, 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig arg1) {

        for(int i=0;i<locationTags.size();i++){
            //call each MarkerCustom's loadGLTexture Method
                //locationTags[i].loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        }


        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);           
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             


        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


    }


}
```

**And Just for reference here is my `MarkerCustom` class**

```
public class MarkerCustom {

    public float xPos;
    public float yPos;
    public float zPos;
    public float yaw;
    public float pitch;
    public Bitmap tagImage;

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;   // buffer holding the vertices
    private float vertices[] = {
            0.0f, -10.0f, -10.0f,        // V1 - bottom left
            0.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f,        // V2 - top left
            0.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f,        // V3 - bottom right
            0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f         // V4 - top right

    };

    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
    private float texture[] = {
            // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
            0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
            1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
            1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)

    };


    public MarkerCustom(float x, float y, float z, float yawAngle, float pitchAngle, Bitmap bitmap) {

        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        zPos = z;
        yaw = yawAngle;
        pitch = pitchAngle;
        tagImage = bitmap;

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);

    }
    /** The texture pointer */
    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        // loading texture
        // Enable blending using premultiplied alpha.
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);



        // generate one texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // create nearest filtered texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, tagImage, 0);

        // Clean up
        tagImage.recycle();
    }
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        // bind the previously generated texture
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // Point to our buffers
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        // Set the face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        // Point to our vertex buffer
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

        //Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this.

```
List<MarkerCustom> myList=new ArrayList<MarkerCustom>();
MarkerCustom entry1=new MarkerCustom(myInt, myString, myBitmap);
MarkerCustom entry2=new MarkerCustom(myInt, myString, myBitmap);

myList.add(entry1);
myList.add(entry2);
```

Comment: problem is the amount of markers is not predetermined, it would be a list from a database query..

would this work?
 for(int i=0; i<results.size; i++){ 
   MarkerCustom tempMarker = new MarkerCustom(results[i][0],results[i][1],results[i][2]); 

   myList.add(tempMarker); 
}

Comment: thank you... sorry about my formatting.. i don't know how to make code blocks in comments..  just to be clear i can say results[i][0]?

Comment: is results an array or list?? because results.size is only for list.for arrays it is results.length.

Comment: i have not descided yet.. basically i will have a table in an online mySQL data base that i will ping via a server side script. (probably php) this is where i get a little confused with java.. in actionscript an array is an array and doesn't have a fixed size.. but in java an array has a fixed size right?

Comment: i thought this would work but i am having trouble actually instantiating the MarkerCustom from the ArrayList passed to my GLSurfaceView in a manner that will be global to that GLSurfaceView  please see my edits above.  I have added both my GLSurface class and the MarkerCustom class in hopes you can better understand what i am trying to do..  Thanks

Comment: Your ArrayList "locationTags" is of type MarkerCustom , if you want to access elements from the arraylist you can do a locationTags.get(index). or you can use a for each loop.

Comment: for(int i =0; i<locationTags.size(); i++){
  
  MarkerCustom markerCustom =locationTags.get(i); // use the markerCustom  object
  }

Comment: If I do that for loop in my on draw method won't each markerCustom over write the last?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13957/discussion-between-erik-and-akhil-dev)

Answer (score 9):

Shorthand:

```
List<MarkerCustom> markerList = Arrays.asList(
    new MarkerCustom(1, "hello", bitMapData1),
    new MarkerCustom(66, "johnHandy", bitMapData2))
};
```

Comment: Worth noting that this list would have a fixed size.

Comment: ok i think this is on the right path.. but would this work if i was going to get a list of data from online, and then say something like:
for(int i=0; i<results.size; i++){
   MarkerCustom tempMarker = new MarkerCustom(results[i][0],results[i][1],results[i][2]);
   markerList.add(tempMarker);
}

Comment: As this list is fixed, the add method is not available. Therefore you would have to use the approach indicated above by Akhil Dev.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think it's easier to create a class Marker (for instance) that has three attributes.
For example:

```
class Marker {

int var1;
String var2;
BitmapData var3; }
```

This way, you are able to store an ArrayList of Markers (ArrayList), and you can access all the information you need.