# How do I add an object to an arraylist within an arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a class to represent a player hand. However I have (in another class) an arraylist where I want to represent a bunch of playerhands. The problem is that  I don't know how to add a card to the hand within the arraylist of many hands. I have a class representing both cards and a deck, which works well. I am just trying to understand how to add an object to an object within an arraylist. Thank you!

```
public class Hand{ 

ArrayList<Cards> hand;
public Hand(){
hand = new ArrayList<Cards>();}

public Class Pile{
ArrayList<Hand> = pile;

public Pile{
pile = new ArrayList<Hand>();
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ pile.add(new Hand()); }
}

public void addToPile(int index, int position, Card card){
 pile.add(index, pile.get(i).add(Card));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i create a list of Objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494088/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-objects-in-java)

Comment: Are you sure you want an ArrayList of player hands, wouldn’t it be better with a Map where the key identifies the player?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Hand> hands = new ArrayList<>();
```

First you have to find your item's index -lets call it i- within `hands`. Then you can get your item from that list like this and put it into another variable.
`Hand myHand = hands.get(i);`
Then you can perform your add operation on `myHand` variable.
Also, you can add a method to your class which takes a card and adds that card to the list of cards(hand).

```
myHand.addCard(card);
```